# OpenGL + GLUT using Ocaml

Tags: opengl, ocaml

I have a problem with installing OpenGL (and GLut) and using it with Ocaml.

I have tried many different packages (under both Linux and Windows) and always got problems
about not found modules or other.

What will be easier : Linux or Windows? What should i exactly do? Which package of bindings is the best? ( are bindings is enough or i need to download some other things?)

Could anyone describe it step by step in a way that can be easy to follow?

Comment: show the exact steps and errors you get

Answer (score 4):

Here are the exact steps :

```
sudo aptitude install liblablgl-ocaml-dev
cp /usr/share/doc/liblablgl-ocaml-dev/examples/simple.ml .
ocamlfind ocamlopt -linkpkg -package lablgl.togl simple.ml -o simple
./simple
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the motivation to walk you through the installation process at the moment, but here are some (hopefully helpful) comments:

You generally want to use OCaml in *NIX because OCaml shows a very clear bias toward it.  In particular, its debugger and profiler are not available in Windows.

One issue I randomly run into when installing new libraries in Linux (which may be a sign that I'm doing something dumb, come to think of it; oh, well) is permissions errors causing module loading errors.  Try tracking down where the relevant libraries were installed and check that they're accessible (e.g. try `ls`ing them as a user; seeing them in a directory is not enough).

For example, I recently installed OCamlMPI but was getting errors about it not being able to find modules even when I gave full paths to them.
It turned out that the directory it was stored in (`$(ocamlc -where)/ocamlmpi`) had a modmask of `0744` (i.e. `drwxr--r--`) when it should have had `0755` (i.e. `drwxr-xr-x`).  After the permissions were changed, the modules loaded and worked just fine.

In fact, that's actually a problem I've run into when installing Python modules, too.  Maybe I *am* doing something dumb somewhere.

Anyway, I hope that helps. :)

Comment: `ocamldebug` works natively on windows since 3.11.0. `ocamlprof` is OS-independent I believe and `gprof` works fine with mingw port at least.